# How would I implement a linear scan on a two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program that determines if there are four consecutive equal integers in a two dimensional array in which the user inputs the dimensions. I have that part written here:

```
public class FourConsecutiveNumbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner rowDimension = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
    int firstInput = rowDimension.nextInt();

    Scanner columnDimension = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of columns: ");
    int secondInput = columnDimension.nextInt();

    int[][] randomTable = new int[firstInput][secondInput];
    for (int row = 0; row < firstInput; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < secondInput; column++) {
            randomTable[row][column] = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 0);
            System.out.print(randomTable[row][column] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

So for instance if a user inputs the dimensions as 5x4, this is what the array would look like if there were four consecutive equal integers in it...

```
2 5 8 7 1
3 2 9 4 7
5 1 2 0 3
8 0 1 2 7
```

In that table, two appear consecutively, diagonally from the first spot. It can also be like this:

```
9 5 3 7 0
2 5 7 3 1
8 5 0 2 9
4 5 1 7 5
```

In this table, five appear vertically down from the second spot.

What I want to do is implement a linear scan through the first row to determine if there are any consecutive equal integers, then do another one down through the columns to determine if there are any consecutive equal integers. Does anyone know how I would do this? I think if it is a match diagonally, I would have it return true if there is a match above or under to the left or right 1 spot, and that happens four times. But I don't know how to do a linear scan any would really appreciate help from someone.

Comment: Wouldn't that be just a `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how relevant this question is anymore, but I will post my answer for others as well. The following method iterates through the whole 2D-array in a single `for`-loop.

When talking about a 2D-array, an element can only have four consecutive numbers, if there is enough space, horizontally and/or vertically. Therefore, I added two other methods `isCandidateForward` and `isCandidateBackward` which will check, if a given element has enough space in front/below or behind it.

See the matrix

```
1 1 2 3 3
4 4 9 9 9
4 4 9 9 9
4 4 9 9 9
```

Here, the elements with number `1` are candidate for "horizontal", "vertical" and "diagonal forward" (up-left to down-right) checks, because there is a sufficient number of elements in front/below them.
`2` is only candidate for "vertical" check.
`3` is candidate for "vertical" and "diagonal backward" (up-right to down-left) checks.
`4` is only candidate for "horizontal" check.
The elements `9` can't be the starting point of a "consecutive number group", since there is not enough space in front/below/behind them.

Following is the code that does exactly that. It should cover all possible cases.

```
/**
 * Checks, if a matrix contains four consecutive equal integers. These can appear horizontally,
 * vertically and diagonally. The matrix is assumed to be of consistent dimensions MxN.
 * This method performs a linear scan.
 * The matrix will be iterated in the following way:
 * E.g.:    0  1  2  3  4
 *       0 [0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ]
 *       1 [5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ]
 *       2 [10,11,12,13,14]
 *       3 [15,16,17,18,19]
 * The outside numbers denote rowIndex (vertical) and colIndex (horizontal).
 * The inside numbers denote the loop index.
 * 
 * @param randomTable the matrix to check
 * @return if the matrix contains four consecutive integers.
 */
public static boolean hasFourConsecutiveIntegers(int[][] randomTable) {
    //Rule out matrices with rows < 4 and columns < 4
    if (randomTable.length < 4 && randomTable[0].length < 4) {
        return false;
    }

    int rows = randomTable.length;
    int cols = randomTable[0].length;
    int elementCount = rows * cols;

    //linear scan; iterates row by row
    for (int index = 0; index < elementCount; index++) {
        int rowIndex = index / cols;
        int colIndex = index % cols;
        int currElement = randomTable[rowIndex][colIndex];

        //The following checks are for preventing IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions in the upcoming code.
        //candidate for horizontal check
        boolean horizontalCandidate = isCandidateForward(cols, colIndex);
        //candidate for vertical check
        boolean verticalCandidate = isCandidateForward(rows, rowIndex);
        //candidate for diagonal up-left to down-right check
        boolean diagonalForward = horizontalCandidate && verticalCandidate;
        //candidate for diagonal up-right to down-left check
        //needs different treatment because of backwards direction
        boolean diagonalBackward = isCandidateBackward(colIndex) && verticalCandidate;

        if (horizontalCandidate) {
            boolean horizontalConsecutive = randomTable[rowIndex][colIndex + 1] == currElement && 
                                            randomTable[rowIndex][colIndex + 2] == currElement && 
                                            randomTable[rowIndex][colIndex + 3] == currElement;
            if(horizontalConsecutive) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (verticalCandidate) {
            boolean verticalConsecutive = randomTable[rowIndex + 1][colIndex] == currElement && 
                                          randomTable[rowIndex + 2][colIndex] == currElement && 
                                          randomTable[rowIndex + 3][colIndex] == currElement;
            if(verticalConsecutive) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (diagonalForward) {
            boolean diagonalFConsecutive = randomTable[rowIndex + 1][colIndex + 1] == currElement && 
                                           randomTable[rowIndex + 2][colIndex + 2] == currElement && 
                                           randomTable[rowIndex + 3][colIndex + 3] == currElement;
            if(diagonalFConsecutive) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (diagonalBackward) {
            boolean diagonalBConsecutive = randomTable[rowIndex + 1][colIndex - 1] == currElement && 
                                           randomTable[rowIndex + 2][colIndex - 2] == currElement && 
                                           randomTable[rowIndex + 3][colIndex - 3] == currElement;
            if(diagonalBConsecutive) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The helper methods `isCandidateForward` and `isCandidateBackward`:

```
/**
 * Checks, if at least four elements can fit consecutively after a 
 * specific index (inclusive) of a dimension (rows/columns). 
 * E.g.:    0  1  2  3  4
 *       0 [0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ]
 *       1 [5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ]
 *       2 [10,11,12,13,14]
 *       3 [15,16,17,18,19]
 *       
 * If you choose rows and rowIndex = 0, isCandidateForward(rows, rowIndex) would return true.
 * Because starting from row 0, there are at least 4 consecutive elements vertically (0,5,10,15).
 * The same is true for (1,6,11,16), (2,7,12,17), (3,8,13,18) and (4,9,14,19). 
 * 
 * @param dimension the amount of rows or columns in the matrix.
 * @param dimensionIndex the index of that specific row or column.
 * @return if at least four elements can fit consecutively starting at that index.
 */
private static boolean isCandidateForward(int dimension, int dimensionIndex) {
    return dimension - dimensionIndex >= 4;
}

/**
 * Checks, if at least four elements can fit consecutively before a 
 * specific index (inclusive).
 * E.g.: [0,1,2,3,4] => indices 3 and 4 would return true, 
 * because you can fit four consecutive elements before them (inclusive).
 * 
 * @param dimension the amount of rows or columns in the matrix.
 * @param dimensionIndex the index of that specific row or column.
 * @return if at least four elements can fit consecutively starting at that index.
 */
 private static boolean isCandidateBackward(int dimensionIndex) {
     return dimensionIndex >= 3;
 }
```

Of course, if you want to check for more or less than `4` consecutive numbers, you'll have to change the methods, and switch the hardcoded numbers for variables. Also, if you want to have more information, like where the consecutive numbers started, or how many groups of consecutive numbers there are, you need to adjust the code as well.

The following code demonstrates the results of different matrices. Just call the method `test()` somewhere in your code.

```
private static void test() {
    int[][] somewhereHorizontal1 = { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 2 }, 
                                     { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, 
                                     { 7, 1, 8, 5, 4 }, 
                                     { 9, 9, 2, 5, 5 } };

    int[][] somewhereHorizontal2 = { { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, 
                                     { 7, 1, 8, 5, 4 }, 
                                     { 1, 1, 1, 1, 2 }, 
                                     { 9, 9, 2, 5, 5 } };

    int[][] somewhereVertical1 = { { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, 
                                   { 3, 1, 8, 5, 4 }, 
                                   { 3, 1, 4, 1, 2 }, 
                                   { 3, 9, 2, 5, 5 } };

    int[][] somewhereVertical2 = { { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, 
                                   { 7, 2, 5, 5, 4 }, 
                                   { 1, 1, 5, 1, 2 }, 
                                   { 9, 9, 5, 7, 5 } };

    int[][] somewhereDiagonalF1 = { { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, 
                                    { 7, 3, 8, 5, 4 }, 
                                    { 6, 1, 3, 1, 2 }, 
                                    { 9, 9, 2, 3, 5 } };

    int[][] somewhereDiagonalF2 = { { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, 
                                    { 7, 1, 4, 5, 4 }, 
                                    { 1, 2, 1, 4, 2 }, 
                                    { 9, 9, 2, 5, 4 } };

    int[][] somewhereDiagonalB1 = { { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, 
                                    { 7, 1, 6, 5, 4 }, 
                                    { 7, 6, 1, 1, 2 }, 
                                    { 6, 9, 2, 5, 5 } };

    int[][] somewhereDiagonalB2 = { { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, 
                                    { 7, 1, 8, 7, 4 }, 
                                    { 1, 4, 7, 1, 2 }, 
                                    { 9, 7, 2, 5, 5 } };

    int[][] nowhere = { { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }, 
                        { 7, 1, 8, 5, 4 }, 
                        { 1, 4, 7, 1, 2 }, 
                        { 9, 3, 2, 5, 5 } };

    //2nd row 6th element: DiagonalB: 9
    int[][] somewhereBigTable = {{1,6,8,4,3,6,2},
                                 {8,3,6,1,5,9,3},
                                 {4,4,6,2,9,8,1},
                                 {7,7,1,9,1,4,9},
                                 {5,2,9,1,1,9,2},
                                 {5,5,6,2,3,3,8},
                                 {8,3,3,5,2,7,7}};

    int[][] nowhereBigTable = {{1,6,8,4,3,6,2},
                               {8,3,6,1,5,9,3},
                               {4,4,6,2,3,8,1},
                               {7,7,1,9,1,4,9},
                               {5,2,9,1,1,9,2},
                               {5,5,6,2,3,3,8},
                               {8,3,3,5,2,7,7}};

    printResults("somewhereHorizontal1", somewhereHorizontal1);
    printResults("somewhereHorizontal2", somewhereHorizontal2);
    printResults("somewhereVertical1", somewhereVertical1);
    printResults("somewhereVertical2", somewhereVertical2);
    printResults("somewhereDiagonalF1", somewhereDiagonalF1);
    printResults("somewhereDiagonalF2", somewhereDiagonalF2);
    printResults("somewhereDiagonalB1", somewhereDiagonalB1);
    printResults("somewhereDiagonalB2", somewhereDiagonalB2);
    printResults("nowhere", nowhere);
    printResults("somewhereBigTable", somewhereBigTable);
    printResults("nowhereBigTable", nowhereBigTable);
}

private static void printResults(String message, int[][] table) {
    System.out.println(message);
    for (int row = 0; row < table.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < table[row].length; column++) {
            System.out.print(table[row][column] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("Consecutive? ==> " + hasFourConsecutiveIntegers(table));
    System.out.println("------------------------------------");
}
```